# How do i get a variable by concatenating?

Tags: php

I understand there are topics which discuss concatenation.
However, i don't seem to figure out what's wrong with this

```
 $LEVEL0 = "Banned";
 $LEVEL1 = "Member";
 $LEVEL2 = "Subscriber";
 $Level =  "LEVEL".$userRow['user_level'];

 echo($Level);
```

It would always just echo the number stored in `$userRow['user_level']`
rather than echo the value of the variable itself.

Comment: @leonardo_palma if you won't answer my question, please don't bother.

Comment: $Level =  "LEVEL".$userRow['user_level'];
echo $Level;

Comment: `$LEVEL` is not defined, as far as I can say. So the string `"$LEVEL"` resolves to an empty string. Next you concatenate the value of `$userRow['user_level']` to that empty string, which leaves you with exactly that value.

Comment: Try this 
''
$LEVEL0 = "Banned";
 $LEVEL1 = "Member";
 $LEVEL2 = "Subscriber";
 $Level =  $LEVEL.$userRow['user_level'];

 echo($Level);

Comment: What is the value of $LEVEL? any value or empty

Comment: @arkascha I just realized that mistake, thank you, but after changing it to   $Level =  $."LEVEL".$userRow['user_level'];echo $Level; just like Amit Visodiya suggested, it just echos the string "LEVEL0" instead of the value

Comment: Try this: `$level = "LEVEL " . $userRow['user_level']; echo $level;`. For this `$userRow['user_level']` has to be defined and contain a value, obviously.

Comment: It means 0 equal to banned 1 equal to member ... Right?

Comment: $LEVEL0 = "Banned";
$LEVEL1 = "Member";
$LEVEL2 = "Subscriber";
$Level =  $'LEVEL'.$userRow['user_level']; that's what i have so far, but it's marked as a string error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$LEVEL0 = "Banned";
$LEVEL1 = "Member";
$LEVEL2 = "Subscriber";
$Level =  "LEVEL" . $userRow['user_level'];

echo $$Level;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$LEVEL = array("Banned","Member","Subscriber"); 

$Levelval = $LEVEL[$userRow['user_level']];

echo $Levelval;
```